# How to use Apache Camel in CXF Rest webservice without Spring

Tags: rest, cxf, apache-camel

In my project, we are not using Spring. Is it possible to use Apache Camel and Apache CXF to build REST service?

I used

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.apache.camel.component.servletlistener.SimpleCamelServletContextListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet-class>
  org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet
</servlet-class>
```

I create a Route class, and I am able to utilize that route. But, this doesn't look like REST service, but looks like plain Servlet call.

How to use CXF here to build REST service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to config the CXF REST endpoint without using Spring.
I think you can use [simple binding](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html#CXFRS-ConsumingaRESTRequestSimpleBindingStyle) to build the route.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could consider apart from the one Willem suggested is using Restlet. Apache Camel provides a nice integration with the framework and super-easy usage.

You can find more info about Restlet and its Apache Camel integration [here](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have an example at:

http://code.notsoclever.cc/camel-cxfrs-jdbc-rest-example/

The example does use Spring but note that the CXFRS component is not configured in Spring.